# objdump -C interfering with --disassemble=<symbol>

Tags: g++, objdump, c++filt

Here is a simple `cpp` file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void test(int x)
{
  std::cout << "x is " << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  test(5);

  return 0;
}
```

After compiling with `g++`, suppose I want to use `objdump` to show the disassembly only of the `test` function (not `main`):

```
objdump a.out --disassemble="_Z4testi"
```

This works. Now, suppose I want to demangle the resulting output using `-C`:

```
objdump a.out -C --disassemble="_Z4testi"
```

The resulting disassembly is empty. How come?

Note: I know that `c++filt` can be used to accomplish this, but I would like to know why `-C` isn't working.

```
objdump a.out --disassemble="_Z4testi" | c++filt
```

g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0

GNU objdump (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38